# Add Dynamically Links to jQuery Mobile

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, jquery-mobile

I read a lot about how to add stuff dynamically in jquery mobile, but I couldn't figure out how to add links.

Currently my solution looks like this:

1. Add a new Page - with id (id="list-1")
2. Creating a Link for it (href="#list-1")

This solution works perfectly in static pages, but I want to do it dynamically. I have tried a lot with `page()` and stuff like that but nothing helped me.

My questions are:

1. How do I add dynamic links & pages?
2. Did I choose the right way to use ids & anchors (#list-1) as links or is there another solution for jquery mobile?

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: `.page()` works only once for one DOM node and its children. You have to recreate an element to use `.page()` to it again

Comment: Thanks @naugtur..your above comment save my valuable time...

Answer (score 4):

To add dynamic links, I have found the easiest way is to just have an event listener waiting for a click on those links. This event listener then saves any parameters you want to pass into the next page you are visiting. You pass the parameters from the list element to the event listener by just specifying parameters within each "li" element.

```
(create the HTML for a list dynamically & store it into list-1-html)
$("div#my-page div[data-role=content]").html(list-1-html);
$("div.list-1 ul").listview();
$("div.list-1 ul").listview('refresh');
```

Then your event listener would look something like:

```
$('#my-page').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    passedParameter = $(this).get(0).getAttribute('passed-parameter');
});
```

When jQuery Mobile loads your next page, you'll probably want to load this page dynamically and you'll have this passedParameter variable available to you. To load the page dynamically, just add a listener that waits for JQM to try to load the page:

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow',function(e, ui){ 
    page_name = e.target.id;
    if (page_name == 'my-page-2'){
        (do something with passedParameter)
    }
});
```

This is the workflow I use with jQuery Mobile and it has been working just fine. I'm guessing in future releases, though, that they'll build in some kind of support for passing dynamic parameters to pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer I did it very similar but my problem is that jquery mobile does not recognize the new link (with id) to the added page :)

Comment: If you are making your links by using listviews, then adding the .listview() and .listview('refresh') will allow JQuery Mobile to recognize the new link.

Comment: If you are making your links without using listviews, and you still want to pass those parameters, you can specify your links as <div> instead of <a> and define a listener on that div. The listener can save your passed parameter specified in <div passed-parameter='blah'> and then call .changePage('my-page-2'). Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah thats what i think about, i have to use it by parameters and with a self coded function for .changePage(). There is no option to use linking of jquery mobile itself ?

Comment: No... as of the Alpha 3 release, there does not seem to be any built in way to dynamically create links that link to dynamically generated pages. There are a lot of other discussions about this laying around the internet. If you find a better or more elegant solution, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Any new enhancement to the DOM should be done before the page initializes. But by default JQM automatically initializes the page once the page is load in browser.

Hence first you need to set autoInitializePage property to false and then call initializePage() method after the new page and links are add to the document. Hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //add a link.
        $("#page1 div[data-role='content']").append('<a href="#page2">Next Page</a>');

        //add a page.
        $('body').append('  <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-title="next page"><header data-role="header" class="header">  <h5>Page 2</h5></header><div data-role="content"><h3>Good Morning...</h3><a href="#page1">Back</a></div><footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h5>&copy; All rights reserved</h5></footer></div>');

    });

    window.onload = function() {
        $.mobile.initializePage();
    };

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">   
        <header data-role="header" class="header">
            <h5>jQuery Mobile</h5>
        </header>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form method="get" action="" data-transition="slideup">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value=""/>              
            </form>
        </div>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h5>&copy; All rights reserved</h5></footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```